# DIRECTUS 1 BULK INSERT when creating X Items instead of (1 INSERT / Item to create) * X

Tags: bulkinsert, directus

I'm trying to find a way to have Directus executing 1 BULK INSERT in PostgreSQL when dealing with items.create scenario in a Child table instead of 1 INSERT per Item to create (which I see in the DB Logs) = optimize performance, especially when dealing with hundreds or even thousands of items.

Thx for any help.

Context : our Mobile app is calling our API and posting hundred of values > this is triggering a flow. Each of these values is then inserted one at a time (=1 INSERT Statement / item), in a child table of SESSIONS = poor performance.